# Trouble trying to use lib protractor-intercept : probably a Javascript async issue

Tags: async-await, protractor, webdriver-io, intercept

I am having trouble trying to use lib `protractor-intercept` which I think is probably a Javascript async issue that I am having.   This code works but it wont print out the `console.log` line.    Any idea on how I might have got this wrong?

```
When('the {string} button is clicked', async (buttonName: string) => {
 var intercept = new Intercept(browser);
 intercept.addListener();
 await page.submitApplication(buttonName);
 intercept.getRequests().then(function(reqs) {
   console.log("Intercepted!! " + reqs);
   //TODO extract a value from submit http query response
 });
 await page.waitForSpinnerButtonFinish();
});
```

And here is my page object method:

```
  submitApplication(buttonName: string) {
    return new Promise(function (resolve) {
      var promised = element(by.css('app form')).element(
         by.cssContainingText('button span', buttonName)).click();
      return resolve(promised);
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find documentation what `intercept.addListener();` returns but to be safe I'd go with `await`. And then I wouldn't mix `.then` with `await`. See if that will do the work

```
submitApplication(buttonName: string) {
    return element(by.css('app form'))
      .element(by.cssContainingText('button span', buttonName))
      .click();
    });
  }
```

```
When('the {string} button is clicked', async (buttonName: string) => {
 var intercept = new Intercept(browser);
 await intercept.addListener();
 await page.submitApplication(buttonName);
 let reqs = await intercept.getRequests()
 console.log("Intercepted!! " + reqs);
 await page.waitForSpinnerButtonFinish();
});
```

Comment: Thanks, that seems to have got me unblocked.  Thank you.   Clears up a couple things about my understanding of the awaits.

Comment: yeah, in the nutshell, whatever returns a Promise, needs `await`. If you are not sure what the command returns, take a look at documentation for the command